# Why does stringr::str_match on a column return a matrix?

Tags: r, stringr, tibble

I'm using `tidyverse` to load the data, so I have a tibble which you can reproduce like:

```
df_1 <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3), subject_id = c("ABCD-FOO1-G001-YX-732E5", "ABCD-FOO2-A011-ZA-892N2", "ABCD-FOO3-1001-CD-742W5"))
```

Now I want to modify `subject_id` to extract just the two first character groups, i.e:

`"ABCD-FOO1-G001-YX-732E5" -> "ABCD-FOO1"`

When I'm running the following code:

`df_1 %>% mutate(subject_id = stringr::str_match(subject_id, "[^-]*-[^-]*"))`

each element of the `subject_id` column is a tibble itself:

```
> class(df_1[1, "subject_id"])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

How do I make sure `subject_id` is a character vector instead of tibble?

Comment: It's not; it's actually a matrix. You're subsetting a tibble in a way that returns a tibble, and then checking the class of that. Tibbles subset differently from base data.frames. See [the docs](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html). `str_match` returns a matrix of matches

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a take on the how to avoid this rather than the why.

As we learn from `?str_match`:

> For str_match, a character matrix. First column is the complete match, followed by one column for each capture group. [...]

So we need to pull the first column from the matrix:

```
df_1 %>% mutate(subject_id = stringr::str_match(subject_id, "[^-]*-[^-]*") %>% .[,1])
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#      id subject_id
#   <dbl> <chr>     
# 1     1 ABCD-FOO1 
# 2     2 ABCD-FOO2 
# 3     3 ABCD-FOO3
```

Also keep in mind, that in your example of `class()`, you subset a tibble. A tibble will always stay a tibble even if it has only 1 cell. See for comparison `class(df_2[1,"id"])`. For more on that have a look at [this chapter from R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html#subsetting).

Comment: I was confused by the fact that when using `data.frame` the matrix from `str_match` seemed to collapse into character vector.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df_1 %>%
     mutate(subject_id = str_extract(subject_id, "^\\w+-\\w+"))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id subject_id
#  <dbl> <chr>     
#1     1 ABCD-FOO1 
#2     2 ABCD-FOO2 
#3     3 ABCD-FOO3
```